# Disable debugging errors?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, error-handling

How I can disable debugging errors in my C++ application, the <kbd>Send</kbd> and <kbd>Don't Send</kbd> error debug window?

I hope there is API for this, because I don't want to edit the registry. Is this possible?

Comment: From what i understand, this is the "Do you want to report the problem to microsoft" dialog when some program crashes.

Comment: A confirmation from the OP with a screenshot would be ideal. If he wants to change the way Windows handles a crashing program, that's folly; he should stop his program from crashing, instead. And it has nothing to do with C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the Windows Error Reporting dialog, then it can be disabled by calling the [SetErrorMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with `SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX`